# Mysql tableA & tableB produce tableC to cross check

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

This my first post.I really confuse with joining **TableA & TableB** and filter by **TableB**.order field and produce **TableOutput** as i stated below.how to achieve below in sql command.

**TableA** contains all the the locations_id of the particular bus route.

> Ex: **ROUTE12** = A > B > C > D

where A is the first pickup point and D is is the last drop point

TableB contains all the location_id of the particular bus route by order

Based on **TableA & TableB** user selected trip seats will be saved like TableOutput.

Ex:***userA*** select seats for **ROUTE12** by selecting locations from 1 to 3 and bought the tickets.Meanwhile, another ***userB*** wants to buy tickets for the same route but choosing location from 1 to 2 so as per logic we shut lock the seats that bought by ***userA*** to avoid conflict, So that is why i need to record ***userA's*** seats in **TableOutput** to cross check and lock the seats.

**TableA**

```
+----------+------------------+----------------+
| route_id | from_location_id | to_location_id |
+----------+------------------+----------------+
|       12 |                1 |              2 |
|       12 |                1 |              3 |
|       12 |                1 |              4 |
|       12 |                2 |              3 |
|       12 |                2 |              4 |
|       12 |                3 |              4 |
+----------+------------------+----------------+
```

**TableB**

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
| route_id | location_id | order |
+----------+-------------+-------+
|       12 |           1 |     1 |
|       12 |           2 |     2 |
|       12 |           3 |     3 |
|       12 |           4 |     4 |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

**TableOutput**

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| booking_id | seat_id | ticket_id | start_location_id | end_location_id |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
|          8 |      16 |        19 |                 1 |               2 |
|          8 |      16 |        19 |                 2 |               3 |
|          8 |      16 |        19 |                 3 |               4 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: For arbitrary numbers of stages, you'd need a recursive query to figure out all the points between A and B, which mysql doesn't support. For a hard-coded limit, you could use as many self-joins as necessary, but that gets ugly, quick. you'd be better off just looping in client code and using multiple queries.e.g. A->B, lock B, B->C, lock C, C->D, lock D, etc...

Comment: Thanks man,will try out and let u know